# $.extend only remembers the last object added

Tags: jquery

I'll try to simplify my case:

```
offenses = {};

$(offenseTableID).find('tr').each(function (rowIndex, r) {
  // building JSON object named "offense" with object with 
  // information from the table row. 
  // console.log shows It's correct. I typically have 3 rows 
  // showing different information. 

// I am trying to extend offenses with what I constructed.                     
 $.extend(offenses, offense);

});

// after I'm done I'm printing my "offenses" JSON object, 
// expecting it to include everything that was added, but even if 
// I $.extend multiple times - it only remembers the last JSON 
// object that was $.extend'ed  Why? 

console.log(JSON.stringify(offenses));
```

Comment: $.extend overrides the first param with other params and last value wins

Comment: any reason not to store offenses in array and just use array.push?

Comment: so no append for JSON objects?

Comment: @RM1970 it doesn't make sense to append for objects. objects have key/value pairs, for you to add something to it, you would need a unique key to store it in. `{{foo:'bar'},{bar:'foo'}}` isn't a valid object. `{somestr:{foo:'bar'},someotherstr:{bar:'foo'}}` would be valid.

Comment: so if I have `{"name": "john"}` in JSON 1, and `{"name:","paul"}` in JSON 2, how can I merge them to have a single JSON with `{{"name": "john"},{"name:","paul"}}` ?

Comment: Where is `offense` defined ?

Comment: you can't, that's not valid. It looks like what you really want is an array.

Comment: Please stop calling objects JSON. they aren't json, they're objects. It isn't json until you convert it to a string.

Comment: inside the function where I say I'm building it. I'm simply `offsense = {.....`

Comment: So, `obj = {"name": "John"}` is an array of one object? what is the type of the object inside of it? key-value?

Comment: no RM...that is a single object, you want an array of objects and that is definitly not what `$.extend` does

Comment: and how would that be defined? = `array = [{"name": "John"},{name":"paul"}]` ?

Comment: @RM1970 `[{"name": "John"}]` is an array of one object. `[{"name": "John"},{name":"paul"}]` is an array of two objects.

Comment: Ok. I think I got you. thanks. I'll convert to array and push to it, then use the JSON stringily to convert to JSON.

Comment: yes...exactly RM...so each iteration will add new object to array

Comment: @RM1970 maybe you want an object where each property is an array of the values of that property found in all the objects you iterated through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because objects must have unique keys. you can't simply append a new object to an existing object and expect it to be useful. What you actually want is an *array* of objects.

```
offenses = [];

$(offenseTableID).find('tr').each(function (rowIndex, r) {
  // building object named "offense" with object with 
  // information from the table row. 
  // console.log shows It's correct. I typically have 3 rows 
  // showing different information. 

  // I am trying to extend offenses with what I constructed.                     
  offenses.push(offense);

});
```

This will result in an array that looks like this:

```
[{name:'bob'},{name:'frank'}]
```

you can then stringify this to json:

```
[{"name":"bob"},{"name":"frank"}]
```